# Linear combination of a continuous function's values at end points of an interval.

Tags: calculus, continuity, upper-lower-bounds

Assume there is a function $f(x)$ continuous on a closed interval $[\xi,\eta]$. Is it possible to show that there exists a point $\gamma\in[\xi,\eta]$ such that the following is true?

$$ |a f(\xi) + b f(\eta)| \leq |a+b| |f(\gamma)|$$

UPD: $a$ and $b$ are given real numbers.

Comment: The problem arises when deriving the error term for Midpoint or Simpson's quadrature rule. E.g here https://www.math.ucla.edu/~yanovsky/Teaching/Math151A/hw6/Numerical_Integration.pdf error terms of the Taylor expansion and the finite difference approximation are taken in the same point $\xi$, which is not clear to me. If I take the error terms in two different points $\xi$ and $\eta$ and show the inequality above, I will be satisfied with the approach in the note.

Comment: What are $a$ and $b$? Are they given or can I choose them as well?

Comment: Hint: In fact it's easy to show that there exists $\\gamma\in\{\xi,\eta\}$ with this property (and continuity has nothing to do with it)...

Comment: @Ingix, thanks for response! I have updated the problem. $a$ and $b$ are given real constants.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for your response! I suspect the solution should be simple, but it's possible I don't see something obvious. If continuity is not necessary - the better.

Comment: I told you that either $\gamma=\xi$ or $\gamma=\eta$ works. So think about what would make it work if $\gamma=\xi$...

Comment: Maybe you misread @DavidC.Ullrich 's hint. He says that one of $\xi$ and $\eta$ can be chosen as your $\gamma$. That I can prove when assuming that $a,b>0$. Note that $a$ and $b$ can't be arbitrary real numbers if you want to hope for the inequality to be true. For example $a=-b$ is a problem case.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Right, I'm sorry, I actually misread the brackets. So do I understand it correctly that depending on the coefficients $a$ and $b$ and the function values, I just pick a point from ${\xi,\gamma}$ so that the inequality holds? What if I am not lucky and I face a case like that described in the answer below? As I said back, I need it to understand the approach to Simpson's quadrature error analysis described in the note.

Comment: I misread something as well - forget what I said, the Answer is the right answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, not in general.  For instance if $a=1$ and $b=-1$ the right-hand side will always be $0$, but the left-hand side will be positive if $f(\xi)\neq f(\eta)$.  Even if you require $a+b\neq 0$ it will still not be true, since you can start with a counterexample where $a+b=0$ and then perturb $b$ by a small amount and the right-hand side will stay close to $0$ (uniformly in $\gamma$ since $f$ is bounded).